# How to subtract two floating point numbers derived from a string

Tags: string, bash, shell, floating-point, subtraction

The floating point numbers come from an output string. Here is my sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash

    output="0.15 0.11"
    cputime=${output[0]}
    gputime=${output[1]}
    echo $cputime $gputime

    diff=`echo "$cputime - $gputime" | bc`
    echo $diff
```

Comment: You're nearly there, the only problem is that `cputime` contains `0.15 011` and `gputime` contains the empty string… you'll have to cut the string `output` to have the corresponding parts in the corresponding variables! (did you try `echo "$cputime"` to check what's going on?).

Comment: You are right. I just checked and found: echo $cputime gives
0.15 0.11

Comment: Add a new line with `output=($output)` before line with `cputime=`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code to separate the values can be better written with:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="0.15 0.11"
cputime=${output%% *}
gputime=${output##* }
diff=$(echo "$cputime - $gputime" | bc)
echo $diff
```

`##` and `%%` are, respectively, the `removal-of-longest-prefix` and `removal-of-longest-suffix` operators, deleting either everything from the first space onwards (`<space>*`) or everything up to the last space (`*<space>`).

The reason your current code doesn't work is because `$output` *isn't* an array for which the two values are in separate indexes, as it would be had you done something like:

```
output=("0.15" "0.11")
```

Alternatively, since you're already calling an external executable `bc` anyway, you could shorten the code with some added `awk` magic:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="0.15 0.11"
diff=$(awk '{print $1 - $2}' <<< "$output" | bc)
echo "$diff"
```

Comment: In you "awk magic" solution: yeah, `awk` is really magic. In fact, it's so magic that it performs the arithmetic operation: your `bc` is useless.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the values are separated by a single space:

```
$ echo "$output"
0.15 0.11
$ tr ' ' - <<< "$output" | bc -l
.04
```

Comment: why `tr`? `printf '%s\n' "${output/ /-}" | bc`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Yup just noticed. Updated answer

Comment: or `bc <<< "${output/ /-}"`